# Privacy policy is partially translated in French and German StackOverflow careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, privacy, localization

Go to [Stack Overflow Careers privacy policy](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/privacy-policy), scroll down and select French or German at the bottom of the screen.

The page becomes a mismash of the selected language and English.

Here's an example of a small part of that page in its current Germglish incarnation.

[image: Germglish]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops, the translations had been broken following some modifications on the page.

We just got the translations back, it should be all good now.

Thanks for your report!